# How to find the particular solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the particular solution to the following equations?

$1. mu''+ku=P_o \\
2. mu''+ku=P_o \sin(wt) \\
3. mu''+ku=kvt
$

I know that the particular solutions for them is

$1. u_p(t)=Po/k \\
2. u_p(t)=C \sin(wt)\\
3. u_p(t)=vt
$

I just don't understand how they come up with those particular solution to their perspective differential equations. Are they just dividing it by $k$?

I tried using the polynomial characteristics solution but somehow I am not getting the same answer at all.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Any thoughts on the answers you have received, Tsendee?

Comment: I think I need to go to the basics. I haven't studied math for years and lot of information is already forgotten. I think I understand what you are saying but I am just having a hard time correlating it to the solution to my questions.

Comment: OK, I worked through an example. Better?

Comment: Thank you for taking time to reply me back and solved an example. It is making sense now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u$ be a function of $t$, let $T$ be some constant-coefficient linear differential operator (for example, $T(u)=m\ddot u+ku$), let $C,\omega,v$ be constants. Then

1. a particular solution to $T(u)=C$ is $u(t)=D$,
2. a particular solution to $T(u)=C\sin(\omega t)$ is $u(t)=D\sin(\omega t)+E\cos(\omega t)$, and
3. a particular solution to $T(u)=vt$ is $u(t)=Dt+E$,

where $D,E$ are constants which you evaluate by substituting the formula given for $u$ into the equation for $T(u)$ and solving for $D,E$.

There are exceptions, when the form given above for the particular solution is already a solution of the homogeneous equation $T(u)=0$, but we'll leave that for another day.

EDIT: Let me work through #3 in detail. We want to find a particular solution for $$mu''+ku=kvt$$ I have claimed above that a particular solution is $u(t)=Dt+E$, where we have to work out what the constants $D$ and $E$ are. If $u(t)=Dt+E$, then $u'=D$, and $u''=0$. Plugging these into the equation we are trying to solve, we get $$kDt+kE=kvt$$ Now in order for this equation to be identically true (that is, to hold true for all values of $t$), we must have $kD=kv$ and $kE=0$. The first of these equations tells us that $D=v$, and the second tells us that $E=0$ [we are implicitly assuming $k\ne0$]. So we now know that a particular solution is given by $u(t)=vt$.

Answer (score 1):

The first one is obvious:
$$ mu''+ku=P_o $$
$$ mu''+ku-P_o =0$$
$$ mu''+k(u-\dfrac {P_o}k) =0$$
$$ m(u-\dfrac {P_o}k)''+k(u-\dfrac {P_o}k) =0$$
Now it's homogeneous:
$$my''+ky=0$$
$$\implies u=y+\dfrac {P_0}k$$
And $y$ is the solution to the homogeneous differential equation.